# How can I get the next items of an array after clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

How can I increase

```
var i = 0
```

every time I click on the

```
<div onClick="my()">
```

, so only the next item of the array gets displayed and restart it, after the last item?

```
<div onClick="my()" class="text"> 
                <p id="next-p"> Next</p>
```

```
function my() {
var i = 0;
var names = [str1, str2, str3, str4, str5]; 
console.log(names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store `i` outside the scope of the function so it isn't re-declared to `0` every time you call the function.
2. Increment `i` in the function.
3. You'll also quickly find that you'll want to reset `i` any time it exceeds the length of the array, so add a condition to the function to check for that.

```js
var i = 0;
var names = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5'];

function my() {
  console.log(names[i++]);
  
  if (i === names.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div onClick="my()" class="text"> 
  <p id="next-p"> Next</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the variable you want to increment from outside the scope of the function that increments it.

```js
let counter = 0;

const names = ['John', 'Marie', 'James', 'Jim', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Donald']

function increment() {
  counter++;
  
  // You should check whether the counter/index is out of bounds before accessing
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = names[counter] || 'Out of bounds';
}
```

```html
<button onClick="increment()">Increment</button>

<div id="counter">John</div>
```

With the code as you currently set it, the `i` variable is reset to `0` each time the function is called, so it will always have the same value.

Edit: beware of getting out of bounds with that solution: you should always check the value of the counter/index before doing any array accessing operation to avoid such errors.